# Создание файла с нужными правами доступа

Tags: python

Код сохраняет картинки в папку, но у этих картинок права доступа 660 и из интернета они не видны.

Как сделать так чтобы при сохранении права доступа становились 755 например.

На папку поставил права доступа 755, если в ручную делаю chmod 755 file, то эта картинка становится видной из интернета.

Запускал сервер и от своего пользователя, и от www-data и от root, ни при одном не создаются доступные картинки.

Что ещё возможно сделать? Желательно чтобы не кодом менять права доступа.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cмотрите man umask, аналогичная команда присутствует в unix-shell и в питоновском модуле os.
Маска задаёт какие биты будут выключены при создании файла.

Comment: Не хотел кодом, но устал уже искать причины, сделал так:  
import os, sys, stat  
os.chmod(PATH_filename, stat.S_IRWXO)

Comment: os.umask(022) не работает?

Comment: Тоже работает. Спасибо )